# How to pass request to multiple servers with Nginx

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to pass a single request to multiple servers using Nginx?

Many Thanks

Comment: Yes, the idea is forward the request to multiple servers.

Comment: In general it's not possible with default modules. Use some other server (e.g. haproxy) or write you own module that will do so. But actually, what the real problem?